# Error(E0852)expression must be a pointer to a complete object type(generic linked list)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, generic-list

I'm trying to learn generic linked list but when I added this line to my code

`*(char*)(new_node->data + i) = *(char*)(new_data + i);`

to copy contents of new_data to newly allocated memory(`struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`)
I received two errors:

1.expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

2.'void *': unknown size

I also used `intptr_t` instead of `char*` but it didn't work.

```
struct Node
{
    void* data;

    struct Node* next;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, void* new_data, size_t data_size)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data = malloc(data_size);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

//error
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
        *(char*)(new_node->data + i) = *(char*)(new_data + i);

    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}


int main()
{
    struct Node* start = NULL;

    // Create and print an int linked list 
    unsigned int_size = sizeof(int);
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }, i;
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
        push(&start, &arr[i], int_size);
  /*  printf("Created integer linked list is"); 
        printList(start, printInt);

    // Create and print a float linked list 
    unsigned float_size = sizeof(float);
    start = NULL;
    float arr2[] = { 10.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.5 };
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
        push(&start, &arr2[i], float_size);
    printf("Created float linked list is"); 
        printList(start, printFloat);*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing vital information, like types of some objects. Please create [mcve].

Comment: We can't help with incomplete code. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @user694733 sorry I added my rest of code

Comment: @kaylum sorry I added other required parts of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do pointer arithmetric on `void*` pointers. You need to cast *before* increment:

```
for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    *((char*)new_node->data + i) = *((char*)new_data + i);
```

But I would recommend you replace the entire loop with standard library functions `memcpy` or `memmove` from `string.h`.

```
memmove(new_node->data, new_data, data_size);
```